# If $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ is a subset of $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

The question is about $\sigma$-algebras and to prove or give a counter-example to the statement that for $X$ a random variable, $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X^2)$.

I think the statement is false. Suppose $X(\omega) = \omega$ (e.g. $N(0, 1)$). Then $(-\infty, a) \in \sigma(X)$, $(-\infty, b)$ is a Borel subset but $(-\infty, a) \not \in \sigma(X^2)$. This because $(X^2)^{-1}((-\infty, b)) = (-\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{b})$ but you can't use unions and complements involving $(-\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{b})$s to get $(-\infty, a)$.

Is this right?

Comment: The opposite is true: $\sigma(f(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$ for any measurable function $f$.

Comment: A $\pm 1$ valued random variable $X$ gives a simpler counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite is true: more generally, $\sigma(f(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$ for any measurable function $f$.

To get a simple counter-example of your inclusion, take a non-degenerate random variable $X$ distributed on $\{-1,1\}$. Then $X^2$ is degenerate: it is constant, equal to $1$. And then $\sigma(X^2)$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, which of course does not contain the non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$.